# Zoo Visitor with playa and shared entries

Tags: playa, zoo-visitor

I have a Zoo Visitor (ZV) channel with different member groups (teachers, students). Within the channel, I have a playa field pulling in the ZV teacher entries. When students register they’ll select one teacher via the playa field.

On the individual teacher pages, I need to show all of the students who’ve selected that specific teacher. So, I'd need to pull all of the student entries that share the current logged in teacher member.

Would this be done with the coparents module? If not, what's the correct playa module to be used with zoo visitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at this thread?

Sounds like you need to do a reverse-relationship lookup with the exp:playa:parents tag:

[Getting reverse related entries via Playa](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2481/getting-reverse-related-entries-via-playa)

Comment: Hey Jae, thanks for the response. I did see that thread and tried using in my template with no success. I guess I don't understand the proper Zoo Visitor parameter for the parents tag to do its magic.

Comment: Since Zoo Visitor just acts as exp:channel:entries tag, there should not be an issue with ZV. 

What you may want to do is move the Playa code as an included template and pass the entry_id of the profile entry:

{...ZV tag...}
{embed="includes/playa_tag_template" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
{/....ZV tag...}

And have the reverse lookup inside the playa_tag_template.

Comment: Jae, you're my hero. I was missing the entry_id thread :/. {exp:zoo_visitor:details member_id="{zoo_visitor_id}"}{embed="_includes/.embed-playa" entry_id="{entry_id}"}{/exp:zoo_visitor:details}

Comment: Glad you got that going!

Comment: I actually noticed an issue today with the students being shown. All of the students who've selected _any_ teacher are showing up, instead of only those students who've selected the teacher currently logged. I think it's the same [idea](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2241/playa-and-zoo-visitors-conditional-to-check-a-match-does-give-an-error?rq=1) here.